# SpringBoot in IntelliJ. unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, intellij-idea, client-certificates

IntelliJ Community Edition, Java8, Spring Boot 2.1.11

Trying to do a basic linkedIn course (Building Reactive apps with Spring Boot2 by Chris Anatalio)

I am unable to run the application. It uses an embedded Mongo DB.

```
failed
:ReactivespringApplication.main()
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.MongodExecutable]: Factory method 'embeddedMongoServer' threw exception; nested exception is de.flapdoodle.embed.process.exceptions.DistributionException: prepare executable
de.flapdoodle.embed.process.exceptions.DistributionException: prepare executable
java.io.IOException: Could not open inputStream for https://downloads.mongodb.org/win32/mongodb-win32-x86_64-3.5.5.zip
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

**Update:**

I found that LinkedIn provides an 'end' code set for each lecture. I downloaded and imported it and it ran fine. I dont know what is different. Did a WinMerge but no obvious differences.

Comment: You may have a proxy that substitutes SSL certificates with a self signed one making HTTPS downloads from the JVM fail. One of the solutions is to install the CA of your self signed cert into the JVM keystore, see https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000094584-IDEA-Ultimate-2016-3-4-throwing-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target-when-trying-to-refresh-gradle?page=1#community_comment_115000405564 .

Comment: @CrazyCoder It did not work for me :(

Comment: @CrazyCoder why is it trying to download mongo db 3.5.5? see https://github.com/flapdoodle-oss/de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo/issues/279

Comment: @CrazyCoder I found that LinkedIn provides an 'end' code set for each lecture. I downloaded and imported it and it ran fine. I dont know what is different. Did a WinMerge but no obvious differences.

Comment: 1- can you publish the source code somewhere for us to try (if the licensing allows it)?
2- are you running this behind a corporate network?

Comment: @gumol if you have a USA public library account, you have free access to the same course at Lynda.com

Comment: I tried and it worked. Can you try using a container (i.e. openjdk)? Map the volume of the source code to the working directory of the container and try running the app using gradlew.
example:
`docker run --rm -v "$PWD":/usr/src/myapp -w /usr/src/myapp openjdk:8 gradlew build`

Comment: @gumol thanks for looking into this. I found that LinkedIn provides an 'end' code set for each lecture. I downloaded and imported it and it ran fine. I don't know what is different. Did a WinMerge but no obvious differences. With this workaround, it should be okay.

Answer (score 1):

Been in the same situation, Root cause is that you are behind a proxy server which requires ssl certificate to communicate/download.

Resolution:
1. Try different network, this worked for me when I connected to a mobile hotspot. 
2. import/create a ssl certificate or bypass ssl, am also still exploring this path.